# Dataframe data handling or SQL Query in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, data-frame, data-management

I'm trying to perform an SQL query in ArcMap with the following data set, and I have not been able to solve the problem.

[image: Ar]

The idea is to keep all the information of the columns, but for example if the column "sens" has the value "S1" discard the value "S2_adjusted" that has a value of "NaN" but leave the column "S1_Adjusted". The same process for the data with value "S2" in the "sens" column, that is, leave only the value of "S2_adjusted" and discard "S1_adjusted". Without losing information in other columns.

I am using Arcmap 10.6.1 and the data comes from an Excel file.

Do you think that an SQL query is the correct approach?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of ArcMap in use and the type data source of this table (and if Enterprise geodatabase, which RDBMS and what release). Normalizing a "adjusted_sensor" field would seem to be indicated, but that would require a CASE construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would handle this problem would be to generate a new empty field and populate it using the [field calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm). This way you will not lose any data and can keep your original data without any modifications to the fields.

"New Field" =

```
reclass(!sens!, !S2_adjusted!, !S1_adjusted!)
```

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def reclass(a, b, c):
    if (a) == 'S1':
        return (c)

    elif (a) == 'S2':
        return (b)
```